# Regarding data binding by knockout js and value change

Tags: knockout.js

here two textboxs and one span is bind by knockout. the example i got is very easy to understand. here is the code.

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>

var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
```

when the code run the whatever value are passing that is reflected but when i change one textbox value then changed data is not reflected immediately when `keyup` occur but when focus change then changed data is reflected in span. so guide me if i want to change data on keyup then what i need to change in code. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `valueUpdate` binding for that:

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
```

Here is a link to documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in an additional value `valueUpdate` in your databind.

> - valueUpdate
>
> If your binding also includes a parameter called valueUpdate, this
>   defines additional browser events KO should use to detect changes
>   besides the change event. The following string values are the most
>   commonly useful choices:
>
> - "keyup" - updates your view model when the user releases a key
> - "keypress" - updates your view model when the user has typed a key.
>     Unlike keyup, this updates repeatedly while the user holds a key down
> - "afterkeydown" - updates your view model as soon as the user begins
>     typing a character. This works by catching the browser’s keydown event
>     and handling the event asynchronously.
>
> Of these options,
>   "afterkeydown" is the best choice if you want to keep your view model
>   updated in real-time.

From http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

So your bindings would be:

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" /></p>
```